# Function with readline is run in for loop before getting a response (Node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, readline

when I want to make a program that makes prompts based on how many the user wants. I have the prompts and the input figured out, the issue is that when the for loop runs, it will ask the question multiple times and not wait for a response. My code:

```
function mainLoop(auth, num){
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= numOfPrompts; i++){
        ask(auth);
        //Create the prompts (unrealated)
    }
}

function ask(auth){
    const r3 = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });
    r3.question("Do you like pie [Y/N]? ", (ans) => {
        ansCheck(auth, ans);
    });
}

function ansCheck(auth, ans){
    if (ans == "y" || ans == "yes"){
        variable = true;
    }else if (ans == "n" || ans == "no"){
        variable = false;
    }else{
        console.log("Invalid answer\n");
        ask(auth);
    }
}
```

If the user inputs 5, the output would be:

```
Do you like pie [Y/N]? Do you like pie [Y/N]? Do you like pie [Y/N]? Do you like pie [Y/N]? Do you like pie [Y/N]?
```

I need the output to be:

```
Do you like pie [Y/N]?
```

> Wait for the answer...
> Answer inputted so check the answer...
> Answer checked so do unrelated things...
> Repeat while needed.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readline is async, so you should not use a loop.

Call `ask` from `ansCheck` after a valid response, just like you do for an invalid answer, but increment the counter there and stop calling when counter >= numSongs.

Another solution is to promisify `ask`, and use `async/await` in the loop.